# How to check field accessiblity of a field that is related to the object being checked

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, bestpractice, field-level-security

While developing secure controller actions for a Lightning Component, I ran across an issue checking accessibility for an `Account` level attribute related a `Contact`.

For example:

```
Schema.SObjectType.Contact.fields.getMap().get('Account.My_custom_field__c').getDescribe().isAccessible()
```

The piece of code, `get('Account.My_custom_field__c')` returns null, and the code throws an exception. I understand why it is happening — the field it's trying to check is technically on the `Account` object, not the `Contact` object.

The way I have written my code is, I have an array of fields, which I later use to piece together a query. I loop over each field, check field accessibility, then if the field is accessible, I add to the queryable fields list.

Here's a full code example, and my current work-around:

```
// this list of fields are these that will be returned to the component
String[] selectableFields = new String[] { 'Id', 'Name', 'Title', 'Email', 'Fax', 'Phone', 
    'HomePhone', 'MobilePhone', 'Account.My_custom_field__c', 'MailingStreet',
    'MailingCity', 'MailingState', 'MailingPostalCode' };        

Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = Schema.SObjectType.Contact.fields.getMap();
List<String> columns = new List<String>();
for(String field : selectableFields) {
    if(DEBUG) System.debug('Selectable field: ' + field);
    // it's not possible to check accessiblilty on second-level attributes, so just add it to the columns list
    if(field.contains('.')) {
        columns.add(field.trim());
        if(DEBUG) System.debug(' - unknown accessiblity due to second level attribute');                
    }
    else if(fieldMap.get(field).getDescribe().isAccessible()) {
        columns.add(field.trim());
        if(DEBUG) System.debug(' - accessible');
    }
    else {
        if(DEBUG) System.debug(' - inaccessible');
    }
}
// id will also be accessible if has access to object, so check if more than 1 column is accessible
if(columns.size() > 1) {
    // get the contact id from the the user's record
    String contactId = [select ContactId from user where id = :UserInfo.getUserId() limit 1][0].ContactId;  
    return Database.query('select ' + String.join(columns, ',') + ' from Contact where id = :contactId');
}
else {
    throw new AuraHandledException(NO_ACCESS_MESSAGE);
}
```

I'd like to avoid having to write `if` this `else` that style code to handle what I'm calling second-level attributes in the code above, but I don't see any way around it.

I realize I can just hard-code the `Account.My_custom_field__c` accessibility check, but I wanted to first see if there are any patterns or best practices to check for field accessibility that take multi-level attributes into account before I do.

Answer (score 2):

I built out a system to do just that for a [`FluentQuery`](https://github.com/apexlarson/FluentQuery/tree/master/src/classes) tool I was working on. Here's the relevant bit of the `DescribeCache`:

```
global class DescribeCache
{
    static final Map<SObjectType, Map<String, SObjectField>> fields =
        new Map<SObjectType, Map<String, SObjectField>>();

    global static SObjectField getField(SObjectType sObjectType, String fieldPath)
    {
        if (sObjectType == null || fieldPath == null) return null;
        if (!fields.containsKey(sObjectType))
            fields.put(sObjectType, sObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap());
        if (!fieldPath.contains('.')) return fields.get(sObjectType).get(fieldPath);

        Relationship relation = new Relationship(fieldPath.substringBefore('.'));
        SObjectField field = fields.get(sObjectType).get(relation.getFieldPath());
        if (field == null) return null;

        SObjectType parentType = field.getDescribe().getReferenceTo()[0];
        return getField(parentType, fieldPath.substringAfter('.'));
    }
    class Relationship
    {
        final String name;
        public Relationship(String name) { this.name = name; }
        public String getFieldPath()
        {
            if (name == null) return null;
            return name.endsWith('__r') ?
                name.replace('__r', '__c') : name + 'Id';
        }
    }
}
```

And the relevant bit of my `Permissions` class minus all the mocking:

```
// change to public static if this part is all you need
protected virtual Boolean canAccess(SObjectType sObjectType, String fieldPath)
{
    SObjectField field = DescribeCache.getField(sObjectType, fieldPath);
    return (field == null) ? false : field.getDescribe().isAccessible();
}
```

The library is open source. Feel free to pull whatever you need out and adjust for your own use.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you can query fields that someone does not have access to and they will just not be included in the results (unless the class runs without sharing).

Since this question was written Salesforce has added tools to simplify this process using the Security class so you don't have to loop through each field and check accessibility individually:

```
String soqlQuery = 'SELECT ..... FROM {your-SObject} ... etc';
List<{your-SObject}> results = Database.query(soqlQuery);
SObjectAccessDecision securityDecision = Security.stripInaccessible(AccessType.READABLE, results);
System.debug(securityDecision.getRemovedFields());
results = securityDecision.getRecords();
```